# How to encoded files in base64 in nodejs after getting details from client-side using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, multer

I am sendind file-details from angular to my app.js as

```
onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    const file: File = event[0];
    console.log(file); 
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    const r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('POST', '/user/upload');
    r.send(formData);
}
```

then in app.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest:'./pics/'});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'),  (req,res) => {
  const body = req.file;
  console.log(body);

  const base64Data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body)).toString("base64");

  console.log(base64Data);
}
```

and my `console.log(body)` gives

```
{ fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: '21329726_1866651723650020_188839340_o.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './pics/',
  filename: '5146c9818ff517c426e34ad84ff3513f',
  path: 'pics/5146c9818ff517c426e34ad84ff3513f',
  size: 94093 
}
```

Now the problem is here -

1 - I don't want to upload my `image/pdf` file in any folder, But it is uploading in `'./pics/'`.

2- I want to upload that file in `cloudinary`  thats why I want to generate `base64` of that file but when I am generating `base64` and and uploading that in cloud, it gives an error.

I think that it is not the correct method for encoding in `base64` OR I am encoding wrong data format.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By providing the options object (in this case `{dest:'./pics/'}`), you're telling `multer` that you want to store the files in that directory. Instead, configure it to hold the files in memory:

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage()
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

According to the docs, the `file` object should also include a `buffer` property, which contains the file data. You should be able to do:

```
console.log(body.buffer.toString("base64"));
```

Comment: Gives an error `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: @Rupesh I've just updated the answer, can you try configuring it like that instead?

Comment: How to make condition that only to convert in `base64` only when it gets complete file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty). A simple and easy solution handle form-data.
Here you can upload files without saving it. I'm using this for save files in `AWS S3`

```
router.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
 let form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
       //here files is array
       const base64Data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body)).toString("base64");
       console.log(base64Data);

    });

});
```

Or else you simply omit the `dest` object. The file will be stored in memory instead of a physical location:

Comment: Add options 'maxFieldsSize' default is 2mb.

Comment: It is getting the large file but not encoding correctly I think For large files it start encoding before getting the full file.

Comment: The file is sending when you select the file

Comment: @Rupesh I'm using same package. It's parsing up to 60mb.

Comment: It is parsing but not encoding on nodejs-side. Can you please check for encoding, I already write the code for encoding.

Comment: There is problem during encoding on large files